# GeoGraphics examples not running correctly

Tags: graphics, version-10, geography, entity

I'm trying to work with the new GeoGraphics functionality in Mathematica 10, starting with the [example given here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/plot-the-density-of-library-books-in-the-united-st.html). None of the code seems to run well for me, though. I try to run the first command:

```
allLibraries = EntityValue["PublicLibrary", "Entities"]
```

and get the output

```
$Failed
```

I feel dumb failing at something so basic but I really can't find many resources on this topic. It seems like their interface is very picky and doesn't behave as they say it should, for example they have [another example here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/show-populations-around-amusement-parks.html) which begins with the code

```
allUSZIPCodes = EntityList[EntityClass["ZIPCode", {"Country", "UnitedStates"}]];
```

which simply returns itself as output for me without downloading any data. If I instead run just

```
EntityList["ZIPCode"]
```

it downloads all zip codes as I was expecting it to.

What am I doing wrong and are there any other resources on this other than the examples I've linked above?

Comment: Perhaps [`FindLibrary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindLibrary.html) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

`EntityValue[]` gives a list of available entity types, and "PublicLibrary" is not among them.  Moreover,

```
EntityValue["PublicLibrary", "EntityCount"]
```

returns unevaluated, whereas

```
EntityValue["PublicSchool", "EntityCount"]
```

returns `103959`.  I would conclude, therefore, that Wolfram jumped the gun with its example.

Returning to this problem later, I noticed that "LibraryBranch" is an available entity type (There are 21857 branch libraries.)  Even with this substitution, the next two lines of the example timed out repeatedly.

```
EntityValue::ctimeout: A computation timed out. >>
EntityValue::nodat: Unable to download data. Some or all results may be missing. >>
```

Note that

```
EntityValue[Entity["LibraryBranch"], "Properties"]
```

lists "City" as a valid property, although "Books" is not.  In any case, I made no further progress.

Answer (score 4):

I think what happened here is that "PublicLibrary" got split into "LibrarySystem" and "LibraryBranch" databases, only the first of which has the information we need.

```
allLibraries = EntityValue["LibrarySystem", "Entities"];
cities = EntityValue[allLibraries, 
   EntityProperty["LibrarySystem", "City"]];
books = EntityValue[allLibraries, 
   EntityProperty["LibrarySystem", "Books"]];
booksInTheCities = {#[[1, 1]], Total[Last /@ #]} & /@ 
   GatherBy[
    Select[Transpose[{cities, books}], 
     FreeQ[#, _Missing, \[Infinity]] &], First];
coords = EntityValue[(First /@ booksInTheCities), "Position"];
booksAndPositions = Transpose[{coords, Last /@ booksInTheCities}];
projection = {"LambertAzimuthal", 
   "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{37.1558, -95.883}]};
data = {GeoGridPosition[#1, projection][[1]], #2} & @@@ 
   booksAndPositions;
weightedData = WeightedData @@ Transpose[Take[data, All]];
bookDensityP = SmoothKernelDistribution[weightedData, "Silverman"];
bookDensity[{lat_Real, long_Real}] := 
  With[{xy = 
     First[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{lat, long}], projection]]}, 
   Flatten[{xy, PDF[bookDensityP, xy]}]];
{{latmin, latmax}, {longmin, longmax}} = 
  GeoBounds[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]];
bookPlot = 
  ContourPlot[
   Sqrt[Last[bookDensity[{lat, long}]]], {long, longmin, 
    longmax}, {lat, latmin, latmax}, Frame -> False, PlotRange -> All,
    Contours -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ContourStyle -> None];
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", bookPlot}], 
  CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"], GrayLevel[0.3], Opacity[1], 
  PointSize[0.001], Point[coords]}, 
 GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]]
```

There is a lot of data, so this takes a while to download, and I made a couple of changes to the `GeoGraphics` call to use the "Polygon" property of the "CountryData" entity,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I find its useful in cases with curated data to see what Wolfram Alpha does for a similar query/function.

In this case it does seem there is underlying data for public libraries in W|A, so this is possibly just an access/terminology problem.   Will explore a bit further and edit this post.

From MMA try:

```
== public library <ctrl-enter>
```

and go from there.

Example direct from W|A below.

[image: WolframAlpha Library query]